# why some of my html content is getting removed after adding some php code?

Tags: php, html, mysql, web-development-server

after adding some PHP code the code below that is getting removed. if I remove the PHP part then it is working fine. even in the source code the below HTML code is not showing

```
    <div class="row data">
                    <div class="row info">
                        <div class="datatitle">Education</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="grad-fetch row">
                        <?php
        session_start();
        $hostname = "127.0.0.1";
        $username = "root";
        $db_password = "";
        $db_name = "resume";

        $conn = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $db_password, $db_name);
        if(!$conn){
            die("connection failed : ".mysqli_connect_error());
        }

       /* $sql =  graduation(degree_status ,college ,start_year ,end_year ,degree ,stream ,performence_scale ,performence_marks)*/


        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM graduation ';

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if (!$result) {
            die("Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn));
        }  
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $deg= $row['degree'];
            $str= $row['stream'];
            $str_yr= $row['start_year'];
            $end_yr= $row['end_year'];
            $clg= $row['college'];
            $prf_scl= $row['performence_scale'];
            $prf_mrk= $row['performence_marks'];
        }
    ?>
        </div class="row">
            <h5>
                <?php
                    echo $deg;
                    echo $str;
                    echo $str_yr;
                    echo $end_yr;
                ?>    
            </h5>
            <div>
                <?php
                    echo $clg;
                ?>
            </div>
            <div>
                <?php
                    echo $prf_scl;
                    echo $prf_mrk;
                ?>
            </div>
        <div> 

     <?php   
        exit;
        mysqli_close($conn);
    ?> 
                    </div>


                    <div class="row dialouge"><h4>Tell us bit about your education</h4></div>
                    <div class="col userinfo">
                        <div class="row discipline" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#graduation-modal" id="grad">Graduation
                            <i class="fa fa-plus education-fa-plus fa-x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row discipline" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#hs-modal">XII(Higer Secondary)
                            <i class="fa fa-plus education-fa-plus fa-x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>      

                        <div class="button-container">
                            <a href="student.php" class="previous">PREVIOUS</a>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
```

if I'm not adding the PHP code then the all the contents are showing but after adding the below part is not showing. I don't understand what is wrong here

Comment: Narrow it down to a [mcve].  Small clear example of the problem, not the whole page.  But generally, this can indicates that there is a bug in the PHP section.  Check your error logs, you might see something.

Comment: _after adding some PHP code_ , which php code specifically? All of them?

Comment: I just noticed, `exit;` will stop the execution right there.  Remove that and see.

Comment: @Nic3500 I got it. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php   
    exit;
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

You need to remove exit from your code as it will stop the execution right there.